# Reconfirm subscribers in Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

In preparation to GDPR i have to send  a re-confirm message to all subscribers, My client has sent me an example seemingly using Mailchimp where the subscribers can reconfirm that they do wish to continue a subscription by simply pressing a button "I wish to continue to subscribe". I have done lots of research and going through the settings at Mailchimp but cannot find any information on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.
I did however find this [Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49535932/1168770/), and have been in contact with the developer who found another way to consolidate his lists.

The link on the button used in both exemples are coded like this:

```
https://xxxxxxx12.list-manage.com/track/click?u=xxxxx&id=xxxxx&e=xxxxx&data=xxxxx|0|xxxxx&sdata=xxxxx=&reserved=0.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is a typical intermediate tracking url that mailchimp inserts instead of the underlying link and is unique to each email, link and user. Hence you can 'abuse' this to [use link tracking as reconfirmation as I described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51307259/630074).